# Loop through list of stock tickers with finance

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to import fundamental data for multiple stocks with yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
ticker.info["priceToBook"]
```

Returns Apples P/B of 15.9 as expected

But what if I want to loop through a list of tickers, like

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'TSLA']
```

and save them to a df or list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through the tickers you want and add them to a dictionary (or whatever you want)

```
dictionary = {} 
tickers = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'TSLA']
for t in tickers:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(t)
    dictionary[t] = ticker.info["priceToBook"]
```

Comment: this returns:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-869964ccbd66> in <module>
      3 for t in tickers:
      4     ticker = yf.Ticker(t)
----> 5     dictionary[t] = ticker.info["priceToBook"]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @NRVA you need to declare the dictionary variable as a dictionary explicitly. I've edited the answer to reflect that. You can do whatever you want with the values though. They don't need to be in a dictionary...that's just an example.